# Where should i put downloader classes in MVVM?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I've written a download manager app for Android. Now i want to refactor it's structure to MVVM. but i have some questions.

1. Into what layer I should move`downloader` classes such as `DownloadManager.java` (which manages download queue, etc), `Downloader.java` (which creates an empty file then downloads data and write into that empty file), etc?
2. into what layer i should move `Application` class which is responsible for creating database for the first time?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 layers,

- View(Activities, Fragments, CustomView, ..)
- BusinessLogic(Presenter, Viewmodel, ..)
- Data(Repository, ..)

Downloader.java should be in the Data layer